# import only x amount of rows from a dump file

Tags: mysql

I am importing a table from a mysqldump file that has 35 million rows. I am doing some testing and just want a subset of this table (like 1 million rows...doesn't matter which ones)...is there a way to do this?

Comment: What OS are you on? How are you importing the dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can consider to use mysqldump, which support where, like

```
mysqldump your_db your_huge_table --where "1 limit 1000000"
```

The above will generate a dump with 1 million rows

Answer (score 0):

use LIMIT so that  you can control how many data will be displayed.